# Understanding passing of polymorphic types in Standard ML

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I am working on some exercises to help my understanding of SML and find I am having a hard time understanding how generic/polymorphic types are passed into functions.

I am given the following initial information:

```
datatype 'a tree = Leaf | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree


val testTree = Node (Node (Node (Leaf, ("a", 107), Leaf), ("c", 417), Node (Leaf, ("e", ~151), Node (Leaf, ("o", ~499), Leaf))), ("s", 35), Node (Leaf, ("u", ~387), Node (Leaf, ("y", 263), Leaf)))

fun nameCompare (n1: name, n2: name) : order = String.compare (n1, n2)

fun treeLookup cmp =
let
  fun lkup (x, btree) =
     case tree of
        Leaf => NONE
      | Node (lt, y, rt) =>
           (case cmp (x, y) of
               LESS => lkup (x, lt)
             | EQUAL => SOME y
             | GREATER => lkup (x, rt))
in
  lkup
end
```

When I try to call `treeLookup` I continue to get type matching errors.
For example this is what I may be calling

```
treeLookup nameCompare ("a", testTree)
```

and Ill get an error like this

```
treeLookup nameCompare ("a", testTree);
                             ^^^^^^^^
Type clash: expression of type
(string * int) tree
cannot have type
string tree
```

What do I need to do in order to satisfy the type of the tree when passing it to treeLookup?

Answer (score 1):

In your tree

```
a' : ("a", 107)
```

`treeLookup` calls the `cmp` on every element and the one you passed. You passed in `nameCompare` which takes two strings and a string, and `"a"` which is a string. That means your tree should only have strings in it.

To solve that you'll probably want to make your tree be a map, effectively comparing only on the first value of the pair:

```
| Node (lt, (k,v), rt) =>
           (case cmp (x, k)
```

Possibly changing the definition as well:

```
datatype 'k 'v tree = Leaf | Node of 'k 'v tree * ('k * 'v) * 'k 'v tree
```

Alternatively, you can change your comparison function to take `('a * 'b)`, but that means that e.g. you'd need to do `treeLookup` with an element `("a", 107)` which would try to match *both* fields.

Comment: Looks like I am going to have to go with the second option since I am unable to change the tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing a string against an item in the tree, which is a `string * int`.

You could always change your comparison function; something like

```
fun nameCompare (n, (k,v)) = String.compare (n1, k)
```

should do.